# caFree – не могу полностью закрыть форму

Tags: delphi

Есть две формы, одна главная, другая не модальная.

Project:

```
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2 := TForm2.Create(self);
  Form2.Show;
end;

procedure TForm2.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
end;
```

Нужно не просто закрыть форму `Form2`, а совсем убрать из памяти. (даже указатель) приравнять к нулю (`Form2.Free; Form2 := nil;`).

В помощи Delphi сказано, что:

> caFree - The form is closed and all allocated memory for the form is freed.

Но нужно чтобы выполнялось:

```
begin
  if Form2 = nil then
    showmessage('Form2 not exists');
end;
```

Если я делаю:

```
procedure TForm2.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.Free;
  Form2 := nil;
end;
```

То летит access…,
Мне нужно, совсем закрыть форму из `Form2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так и занулите

```
procedure TForm2.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
  Form2 := nil;
end;
```

Это конечно не совсем хороший ход, но если сильно нужно иметь зануленную переменную, то должно работать.

Comment: А ларчик просто открывался. :-)

Comment: @Konstantin78 это `Form2 := nil;` надо делать не в `TForm2.FormClose`, а в переписанном деструкторе `TForm2.Destroy` или, в крайнем случае, в `TForm2.FormDestroy`